# Custom Cipher Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the cipher used in [this puzzling post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53689/help-what-is-sistek-saying), if you would like to crack it before looking at the programs use to make it.

---

Several weeks ago, I created a custom cipher for a friend of mine to crack, and I also posted it on Puzzling. Here are the programs I used to create it - I threw them together one morning, and I didn't comment them. I decided to leave them as is - they are self-explanatory to some degree, and I would also like to have my rush-job instinct in variable naming and what not critiqued. I know it's not *good* per say, but since it was a personal project I didn't care. How the cipher works is explained the in answer to the puzzling question, if my code doesn't show you well enough.

I have an encoder and a decoder. They currently assume that `plaintext.txt`, `code.txt`, and `decoded.txt` are in the current directory. The decoder assumes that the code is formatted as the encoder would format it.

---

`encoder.py`

```
import random
import string

text = open("plaintext.txt").read()

#chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*.,?!()- \n"
chars = "(stephn)a*dowjzr.b\nm,uvklc ?qig!fyx-"

def base_10_to_base_6(n):
    s = ""
    while n:
        s = str(n % 6) + s
        n //= 6

    if len(s) == 1:
        s = "0" + s

    if not s:
        return "00"

    return s


def base_10_to_base_26(n):
    s = ""
    while n:
        s = string.ascii_lowercase[n % 26] + s
        n //= 26

    if len(s) == 1:
        s = "a" + s

    if not s:
        return "aa"

    return s

print(text)

result = ""

for letter in text:
    letter = letter.lower()

    if letter not in chars:
        letter = "*"

    coded_char = base_10_to_base_6(chars.index(letter.lower()))

    print(letter + ": " + coded_char + " : " + chars[int(coded_char, 6)])

    result += coded_char

len_diff = len(result) % 3

if len_diff != 0:
    result += (3 - len_diff) * str(random.randint(0, 5))

print(str(len(result)) + " " + result)

sets_of_3 = []

index = 3

while index <= len(result):
    sets_of_3.append(result[index - 3:index])
    index += 3

print(sets_of_3)

sets_of_letters = []

for set_of_3 in sets_of_3:
    sets_of_letters.append(base_10_to_base_26(int(set_of_3)))

print(sets_of_letters)

with open("code.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(" ".join(sets_of_letters), file=text_file, end="")
```

---

`decoder.py`

```
import random
import string

text = open("code.txt").read()

#chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*.,?!()- \n"
chars = "(stephn)a*dowjzr.b\nm,uvklc ?qig!fyx-"

def base_10_to_base_6(n):
    s = ""
    while n:
        s = str(n % 6) + s
        n //= 6

    if len(s) == 1:
        s = "0" + s

    if not s:
        return "00"

    return s


def base_10_to_base_26(n):
    s = ""
    while n:
        s = string.ascii_lowercase[n % 26] + s
        n //= 26

    if len(s) == 1:
        s = "a" + s

    if not s:
        return "aa"

    return s


def base_26_to_base_10(n):
    result = string.ascii_lowercase.index(n[0]) * 26 + string.ascii_lowercase.index(n[1])

    result = str(result)

    if len(result) == 2:
        result = "0" + result
    elif len(result) == 1:
        result = "00" + result
    elif not result:
        result = "000"

    return result


def base_6_to_base_10(n):
    return int(n[0]) * 6 + int(n[1])

sets_of_chars = text.split(" ")

print(sets_of_chars)

triplets = []

for each in sets_of_chars:
    triplets.append(base_26_to_base_10(each))

code = "".join(triplets)

print(code)

index = 2

output = ""

while index <= len(code):
    output += chars[base_6_to_base_10(code[index - 2:index])]
    index += 2

with open("decoded.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(output, file=text_file, end="")
```

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: @MarianD what I did bad in my code, what I can do better, optimizations, etc. I haven't coded in Python too extensively.

Answer (score 3):

You may replace the lines as

```
text = open("plaintext.txt").read()
```

with so called context manager approach (see [PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)):

```
with open("plaintext.txt") as pt:
    text = pt.read()
```

which has the advantage of automatically closing the open file, even if an exception is raised on the way.

---

```
sets_of_chars = text.split(" ")
```

is somehow different from

```
sets_of_chars = text.split()
```

in two ways - if there are more consecutive spaces, and if it is applied to the empty string:

```
'abc  def'.split(' ')        # returns ['abc', '', 'def']
'abc  def'.split()           # returns ['abc', 'def']

''.split(' ')                # returns ['']
''.split()                   # returns []
```

Consider which one is more appropriate for your code.

---

```
chars = "(stephn)a*dowjzr.b\nm,uvklc ?qig!fyx-"
```

It is a constant, so by [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) its name should be in uppercase letters:

```
CHARS = "(stephn)a*dowjzr.b\nm,uvklc ?qig!fyx-"
```

---

Both functions for converting from base 10

```
def base_10_to_base_6(n):
    s = ""
    while n:
        s = str(n % 6) + s
        n //= 6

    if len(s) == 1:
        s = "0" + s

    if not s:
        return "00"

    return s


def base_10_to_base_26(n):
    s = ""
    while n:
        s = string.ascii_lowercase[n % 26] + s
        n //= 26

    if len(s) == 1:
        s = "a" + s

    if not s:
        return "aa"

    return s
```

have very similar structure - by the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) why not to substitute them with one common function, e. g. with

```
def base_10_to_other(n, base):
    if base not in (6, 26):
       raise ValueError("Illegal base - allowed values are only 6 and 26")

    DIGIT_SYMBOLS = {6: "012345", 26: string.ascii_lowercase}
    zero_symbol = DIGIT_SYMBOLS[base][0]

    s = ""
    while n:
        s = DIGIT_SYMBOLS[base][n % 6] + s
        n //= base

    if len(s) == 1:
        s = zero_symbol + s

    if not s:
        s = 2 * zero_symbol

    return s
```

Moreover, they are the same in your both modules (`encoder.py` and `decoder.py`) - why don't use the 3rd module for all common functions and `import` from it?
(The same for the other pair of converting functions, of course.)

Comment: That bit about the base conversion functions is very helpful - I knew I should fix it, but I couldn't think of how.

Comment: From the cryptographic point of view (if it is not a toy only): 1) Never ever invent your own cipher  2) Use only cryptographic pseudo-random generators.

Comment: It's just a toy - it's got way too many problems (always has an even number of characters, doesn't use certain letters) to be useful. I'm surprised how long it lasted on Puzzling.

Comment: So I congratulate you for it!

Answer (score 2):

- Always open file using `with statement`. It makes sure that the file is properly gets closed even when an exception occurs.

From [docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

> It is good practice to use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is
>   also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks

```
with open("plaintext.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
```

- Instead of lower-casing each letter you can loop over lower-cased version of `text` itself.

```
for letter in text.lower():
    ...
```

- String concatenation using `result += coded_char` could result in [performance issues](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation). The fast way is to to create a list and then join them together similar to what you're doing with `code = "".join(triplets)`.
- Use [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) and [variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)(Python 3.6+) to provide hints about the type of argument, variables etc. These can also be used by Mypy to statically analyze your code.